# Showing images from database

Tags: php, image, insert

This is my code (adding news into db).

```
if(!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])){
    $extension = end(explode(".",$_FILES['img']['name']));

    $name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['img']['size'];

    if(file_exists("views/admin/uploads/".$name)){
        $errors[] = "File with this name already exists!";
    }

    if($extension != "jpg" && $extension != "png" && $extension != "gif" && $extension != "JPG"){
        $errors[] = "Unknown file format!";
    }
}

if(count($errors)==0){
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `avetisyan`.`$category` (`id`, `category`, `sub_category`, `news_category`, `title`, `img`, `short_content`, `content`, `date`, `lang`) VALUES (NULL, '$category', '$sub_category', '$news_category', '$title', '$name', '$short_content', '$long_content', '$date', '$lang')");
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"views/admin/uploads/".$name);
    echo "<h2 align=\"center\">Successfully added!</h2>";
}
else{
    print "<h3>Errors!</h3><ul><li>".join("</li><li>",$errors)."</li></ul>";
}
```

As you see, the name of the image goes to database, and the image goes to /views/admin/uploads/..

Which is the right way to show this image in news? How?

Comment: `<img>` tag with the `path/to/uploaded/picture.ext` as its `src`

Comment: you need to check if(file_exists("views/admin/uploads/".$name)) then as  you path is fixed you can directy concat path and name and can access image.

Comment: For security reasons, you may want to check the name of the image before it is saved to the database. This can be vulnerable to SQLi and XSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $name = getImageNameFromDB(); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
```

Obligatory note:
mysql_* methods are deprecated and should not be used. In addition your code may be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) attacks. Consider filter you're input or even better, switching to prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"views/admin/uploads/".$name);

You can have this "views/admin/uploads" in config file and fetch it from config and then concatenate with image file name "$name"' while uploading file

Have a separate function which gives image path , in your case "/views/admin/uploads"
Retrieve data from database and for the result loop around to get full image path

Answer (score 0):

Do the query to get all records, loop through the records and do something like this

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `table_name`");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($query); $i++)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            echo '<img src="views/admin/uploads/'.$row['img'].'" />';
        }
    }
?>
```

SIDE NOTE:

```
mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. 
Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an 
API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$image_query = 'select * from `avetisyan`.`$category`';
$img = mysql_query($image_query );
while($get_items = mysql_fetch_array($img ))
{
    echo '<div id="images">';
    echo '<b>'.$get_items['title'].'</b>';
    echo '<br><img src="uploads/'.$get_items['img'].'">';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

with the above code use proper css style to show image

Answer (score 0):

You get the name from the database and echo it as the source in an  tag. For an example, if you're displaying a list of short news articles in category $category with their images (in a very minimalistic layout):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM avetisyan".$category);

echo("<table>");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo("<tr>");
    echo("<td>");
    echo("<img src=\"views/admin/uploads/".$row['img']."\">");
    echo("</td>");
    echo("<td>");
    echo($row['short_content']);
    echo("</td>");
    echo("</tr>");
}

echo("</table>");
```